# angular 6 content projection with reused elements

Tags: angular, components

As far as I know, content projection can be used with `<ng-content select="[header]">` to achieve **multiple content projection**

However, I cannot find documentation on how to reuse a selector for an *ngFor inside the child component.

I'd like to be able to inject content in this fashion:

```
<my-component>
  <span header> Header injection </span>
  <div option> option 1 injection </div>
  <div option> a second option injection </div>
  <div option> three makes a party </div>
  ...
</my-component>
```

and use it in *my-component* like this:

```
<h1><ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content></h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let option of options">
    <ng-content select="[option]"></ng-content>
  </li>
</ul>
```

much like many angular material components are set up.